# Gantt chart on Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm trying to visualize concurrent requests of a given user on a given time frame. I thought that the best way to do so would be using a gantt chart... How can i do that using Application Insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application Insights can visualize service-side telemetry using Gantt chart (dependencies made as a part of a request). At the moment Application Insights doesn't provide a way to visualize client side telemetry the same way. The latter is on backlog (no ETA at this point).

Comment: how can i get the service-side telemetry as Gantt?

Comment: It is shown in request details. App needs to be on 2.3+ (in case of .NET app) for correlation to work.

Comment: can you be a little more specific? i can't seem to find it... my app is on 2.4.latest...